# DIV and TABLE widths not rendering properly using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, firebug

With this html:

```
<div class="sectionheading">User Information</div>  
<table id="UserInputTable" class="xInputTable">
```

...and this CSS:

```
.sectionheading{width:100%; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#28BA87; color:white; text-align:center; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color:Black; border-collapse:separate; overflow:hidden}

.xInputTable {text-align:left; 
                  vertical-align:middle; 
                  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                  border-collapse:separate;
                  overflow:hidden}
table.xInputTable {width:100%; border: solid thin red; border-top-style:none;}
```

The DIV ends up rendering 2 pixels wider in both IE and Firefox (the left borders line up perfectly, the right borders are off by two pixels).  Using the IE web dev toolbar, both elements have a width of 100%.  In Firebug, they have widths of 950px and 948px.  Here is the computed CSS (from IE developer toolbar):

### DIV

```
BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: thin;
BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat;
BORDER-RIGHT: thin solid black;
WIDTH: 100%;
FONT-SIZE: 300;
MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px;
OVERFLOW: hidden;
BORDER-LEFT: thin solid black;
BORDER-COLLAPSE: separate;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
DISPLAY: block;
BORDER-BOTTOM: thin solid black;
BORDER-TOP: thin solid black;
BACKGROUND: #28ba87;
BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: thin;
FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: thin;
LINE-HEIGHT: 1.5;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #28ba87;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: thin;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
COLOR: white;
FONT-WEIGHT: 700;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
```

### TABLE

```
BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: thin;
BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat;
BORDER-RIGHT: thin solid red;
WIDTH: 100%;
FONT-SIZE: 180;
MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px;
OVERFLOW: hidden;
HEIGHT: auto;
BORDER-LEFT: thin solid red;
BORDER-COLLAPSE: separate;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
DISPLAY: block;
BORDER-BOTTOM: thin solid red;
BACKGROUND: white;
BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: thin;
FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: thin;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: white;
LINE-HEIGHT: normal;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: thin;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px;
COLOR: #222;
TEXT-ALIGN: left;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
```

Any idea what concept I'm missing here?

Comment: ... the concept of consolidating your CSS...

Comment: lol....so true...but to be fair to myself, this mess is a result of hours of banging my head against the wall trying everything.

It seems the answers below have shown how to get this to work, but in addition to that, it would be nice to know if there is a fundamental premise of CSS that, had I known, I wouldn't get this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess here, but tables by default have `cellpadding` or `cellspacing` (can't remember which one) set to 2px by default, unless you set `border-collapse: collapse;`.

This doesn't affect the table itself, but the `td`'s *inside the table*.

If my guess is correct, either of the following should work:

- Set `border-collapse: collapse;` in the css for the table
- Put "cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`in the`` tag
- Add a new CSS declaration `table.xInputTable td { padding:0; margin:0; }`

Answer (score 1):

Could be the 2 pixels for each (left and right) border which aren't taken into account when calculating the width.

Comment: I think you may be correct.....but, what do you mean exactly?  The solution is seemingly to **not** set width: 100% in the style applied to the DIV, but **do** set it to width:100% in the style applied to the table...with all margins and padding set to 0, this renders properly.  So what is going on here that doesn't make sense?

Comment: It sure doesn't make sense. All depends on the implementation of the CSS boxmodel by different browsers. (IE vs FF VS Webkit). I gave up on making pixelperfect sites, it's just not worth it. More info here: http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try to not set the width specifically on the div (and maybe the table too). They default to 100% but get calculated slightly different when it's set, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

pb is correct.

When you apply "border" to a table, it will adjust the width to accommodate for the border. DIVs will add the border in addition to the width (as will most elements with a specified width, tables are special).

Hurix is correct that there is no point in adding width 100% to the div since it is a block element and will take up the full width of the parent by default, so you can take it off and it will auto-size to stay inside the parent even with the border added to its width. The table, however, should get the width: 100% if you want it to be full width.

Answer (score 1):

Borders act like padding, so you are adding 2px to your width => **100% + 2px**

Also consider using meyers reset.css to make sure your on level ground before jumping in.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Also you are getting sorta crazy with the all caps thing.

Comment: Ok, but I am adding the same border to both the div and the table, yet one is wider than the other.  Is this just yet another quirk of CSS that must be memorized, or is there an underlying fundamental rule that covers this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, in my opinion, at this point I would roll all the way back to just the html. Use FireBug religiously and only add one CSS attribute at a time to be sure that it doesn't have a negative effect on the layout.

Unfortunately the nature of CSS is that it is full of exceptions and things to consider with inheritance. Starting with just a reset.css, and maybe making all your different major elements a different background color (because that wont change the size like border) can help you see where you elements ACTUALLY reside.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on kmiyashiro and pb I wanted to add that if you wrapped your table in a div with the style "`width:100%; border: solid thin red; border-top-style:none;`" and changed the style on "`table.xInputTable`" to "`width: 100%`" then everything should line up.